# Batch delete SQS messages after batch receiving in boto3

Tags: amazon-sqs, boto3

I am using boto3 to receive_message() in batches. This returns a dict item as specified in the [boto3 documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message).

After receiving the batch of message, I process them one by one and want to batch delete them after they are all processed. I do not want to delete them one by one after processing each single item.

The delete_message_batch() function has a slightly different syntax than the response from the receive_message() function, so I need to reformat the response dict from receive_message() into a suitable format (only using Id and ReceiptHandle).

Is there any easier way to directly use the response from receive_message() for batch deletion?

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I handle the messages. I create a list with the ids and the receipt handles. The ids are not mandatory, you could insert the output of range(10). Also, there is no error checking so you need to take care of that.

```
response = SQS.receive_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    AttributeNames=[],
    MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
    MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
)
delete_batch = []
for message in response.get('Messages') or []:
    # do stuff with each message
    delete_batch.append(
        {'Id': message['MessageId'], 'ReceiptHandle': message['ReceiptHandle']}
    )
if delete_batch:
    SQS.delete_message_batch(QueueUrl=queue_url, Entries=delete_batch)
```

Comment: Making the change from `delete_message` to `delete_message_batch` has created > 5x speedup in my message processing.  This would be higher except `delete_message_batch`has a limit of 10 messages per call.

Answer (score 0):

In Boto3 you can use the Queue resource to delete batches of messages in one call. Here's some code (from a larger example in [GitHub](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/40a75de3f87ee5dcc43aae320b878fb199fc463b/python/example_code/sqs/message_wrapper.py#L165)) that shows how:

```
import logging

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

def delete_messages(queue, messages):
    """
    Delete a batch of messages from a queue in a single request.
    :param queue: The queue from which to delete the messages.
    :param messages: The list of messages to delete.
    :return: The response from SQS that contains the list of successful and failed
             deletions.
    """
    try:
        entries = [{
            'Id': str(ind),
            'ReceiptHandle': msg.receipt_handle
        } for ind, msg in enumerate(messages)]
        response = queue.delete_messages(Entries=entries)
        if 'Successful' in response:
            for msg_meta in response['Successful']:
                logger.info("Deleted %s", messages[int(msg_meta['Id'])].receipt_handle)
        if 'Failed' in response:
            for msg_meta in response['Failed']:
                logger.warning(
                    "Could not delete %s",
                    messages[int(msg_meta['Id'])].receipt_handle
                )
    except ClientError:
        logger.exception("Couldn't delete messages from queue %s", queue)
    else:
        return response

queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=name)
messages = queue.receive_messages(
            MessageAttributeNames=['All'],
            MaxNumberOfMessages=max_number,
            WaitTimeSeconds=wait_time
        )
delete_messages(queue, messages)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to purge the queue. Not sure if it will fit your use case but here is the reference:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.purge

and the code example:

```py
import boto3

REGION_NAME = 'us-east-01'
QUEUE_NAME = 'my-queue01-example'

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', REGION_NAME)
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=QUEUE_NAME)
response = queue.purge()
```

Comment: Oh, also keep in mind that you can't write to a purged queue for 60 seconds after you purged it. Any message that will be sent in that time will be also purged.